# C# - How to use MySQL with reader GetValue function and with for loop

Tags: c#, mysql

In have stored images in my MySQL Database. I can display now these pictures. But unfortunately my code only work for one picture. I want to display all pictures from the table, but with `rdr.Nextresult()` it doesn't work.

I have a PicutreBox Array:

```
PictureBox[] pictureboxes = new PictureBox[30];
```

And I generate new PictureBoxes for each index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pictureboxes.Length; i++)
{
    pictureboxes[i] = new PictureBox();
}
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT image FROM drinks";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
        {
            pictureboxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80 + i * 100, 40);
            pictureboxes[i].Name = "pictureBox" + i;
            pictureboxes[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pictureboxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            pictureboxes[i].Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])(rdr.GetValue(0)));
            panel1.Controls.Add(pictureboxes[i]);
            //rdr.NextResult();
        }
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
conn.Close();
```

ByteArrayToImage function:

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    {
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}
```

When I change `rdr.GetValue(0)` to `rdr.GetValue(i)` the index ist out of range.
How I have to change the code so that I can output all images from a table?

Comment: do a google search on how to use a while loop when calling `command.ExecuteReader()` method, you don't use `if (rdr.Read())` there are plenty of working examples out there online.

Comment: Change if (rdr.Read()) to while (rdr.Read())

Comment: `pictureboxes[i].Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])(rdr.GetValue(0)))` this should be accessed using the column name not the ordinal position
`pictureboxes[i].Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])(rdr.["YourColumn"])` and do proper casting where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user of `rdr.GetValue(0)` is accessing the single column you are returning from your query `SELECT image FROM drinks`. If you try changing that to use your index variable `i`, which is used to access your rows, you will run into the problem you are seeing.

You can change your usage of the `GetValue` method to the following: `rdr.GetValue("image")` and it will work the same as `rdr.GetValue(0)`.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < anzahl; i++)
   {
      pictureboxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80 + i * 100, 40);
      pictureboxes[i].Name = "pictureBox" + i;
      pictureboxes[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
      pictureboxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
                pictureboxes[i].Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])(rdr.GetValue("image")));
      panel1.Controls.Add(pictureboxes[i]);
      //rdr.NextResult();
   }
```